# Execute some operation on new element addition using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of search controls in the page. Now I am using jQuery to perform some initialization on the controls available on the page. For the controls added by ajax, after the page was loaded, I have written a function to complete this initialization by passing the newly created ids to the function. But is there a better solution for this problem something like events where we can use on (live) in case of elements added after the page was loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to the load event:

```
$('#id').load(function (event) {
    // init control
});
```